# Get the String mongo field data type in java

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have fields in mongo-db stored like string, arraylist, objectId, date and so on.. I just want to get the fields in java which have a data-type of string. By far I have written the folowing code:

```
MongoCollection<Document> mongoCollection = database.getCollection(collectionName);
Iterable<Document> fields = mongoCollection.find();
```

But it return all the fields in a collection irrespective of the data-type ,i.e. String is there any other way to get just the field of data-type String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$type` is the operator you are looking for.

```
Iterable<Document> fields = 
     mongoCollection.find(new Document("field", new Document("$type", "string")));
```

[Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "data": {//Reshape as fields are unknown
        "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {//Denormalize
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    "$match": {//Find string fields
      "data.v": {
        $type: "string"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {//Filter the keys
      "key": "$data.k"
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vs7d3hgEql9)

Comment: This won't work in my case as I don't know the field. I have created a connection with database and iterating over the collection. And now in that collection I just want fields which has string data-type.

Comment: `db.user.find({"field":{"$type":"string"}}).pretty();` and also quering this in mongo shell returns me nothing I need to specify the fieldName which I don't know in my case

Comment: You want to find out all the string fields?

Comment: Are you fine with aggregation frameworks?

Comment: yess thanks I converted it in java `AggregateIterable<Document> docs = mongoCollection.aggregate(Arrays.asList
                                    (new Document("$project", new Document("data", new Document("$objectToArray", "$$ROOT"))),
                                            new Document("$unwind", "$data"), new Document("$match", new Document("data.v", new Document("$type", "string"))),
                                            new Document("$project", new Document("key", "$data.k"))));`

Comment: Do these aggregate queries work even in subdocuments?

Comment: Unfortunately no. You need to alter it